ODOO 18 : field description
In the free version of ODOO 18, I can't add the product description field on the website.
I think, I don't find the good view.
I could add the field in product.
How can I do?
Thanks,
I searched in different views, but I don't see where I can add the code

You will find a field named 'E-commerce Description' in Product --> Sales Tab --> at the bottom. This will add product descriptions for any product to the website.
